# Stuggling to set up caching for PyPi server via NGINX/UWSGI

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, pypi

I'm trying to configure caching of an PyPi Server via NGINX/uWSGI and failing miserably.

My `/sites-available/pypi` config is as follows:

```
uwsgi_cache_path /mnt/pypi/nginx-cache
                 levels=1:2
                 keys_zone=pypiserver_cache:10m
                 max_size=10g
                 inactive=60m
                 use_temp_path=off;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/domain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.key;

    client_max_body_size 5M;

    location / {
        uwsgi_cache pypiserver_cache;
        uwsgi_buffering on;
        uwsgi_cache_key $request_uri;
        add_header X-uWSGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/internal_pypi.socket;
    }
}
```

NGINX runs and reports no errors but requesting the same package multiple times does not cache it (proven by curling the URL and observing the header `X-uWSGI-Cache: MISS`) and there is nothing being stored in `/mnt/pypi/nginx-cache`.

Let me know if I can provide any more helpful info, thanks!

References:

- https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver#serving-thousands-of-packages
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, in my case, the pypi server python file needed some changes.

```py
application = pypiserver.app(
    root="/mnt/pypi/directory",
    redirect_to_fallback=False,
    password_file="path/to/file",
    cache_control=3600 #this needed to be added
)
```